# How is ExchangeOnlineManagement PowerShell module related to ExchangePowerShell module?

Tags: powershell, exchangeonline

Please let me understand how **ExchangeOnlineManagement** and **ExchangePowerShell** modules are related each other.

For example [Microsoft Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps) describe cmdlet `Connect-ExchangeOnline` as it comes from **ExchangePowerShell module**, while `Get-Command Connect-ExchangeOnline` returns **ExchangeOnlineManagement** as its source.

Answer (score 1):

Because EXO V1 will eventually be deprecated due to the security concerns around Basic authentication. So Microsoft suggest user to use due EXO V2 module,

And The Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module (abbreviated as the EXO V2 module) enables admins to connect to their Exchange Online environment in Microsoft 365 to retrieve data, create new objects, update existing objects, remove objects as well as configure Exchange Online and its features.

You could check which commands are only available online in the following document.
Or which commands are only available in Exchange online.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/?view=exchange-ps

Comment: Hi. is there any update?If the issue get resolved, you could mark the helpful answer as the best answer. It will make answer searching in the forum easier and be beneficial to other community members as well.